# React Native Can't open url: intent://photos.app.goo.gl/ in apps webview

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webview

I'm opening a url inside `react-native-webview`. The URL is opening fine. But the problem is if I tap on some component in `webview` it will return me

> "intent://photos.app.goo.gl/HvTckEDkdidAhTvC6#Intent;package=com.google.android.gms;xxxxxxxxx" type url.

I want to open it in `webview` only. Its working fine in iOS. For android in some links its working and some links it won't. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was from Web end. The URL coming for photos is getting converted into Short-URL for google photos,But for iOS and other working links in Android it's coming in proper format like below :
https://photos.google.com/share/AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxx
But for broken link for Android its coming as below :
intent://photos.app.goo.gl/HvTckEDkdidAhTvC6#Intent;pXXXXXXXXXXXXX
So the workaround for me was I've replaced Short-URL of broken links with long URL. After converting them to long URL from Web end its working fine. Hope it helps someone who faces the same issue like mine.